# Airplay SDK, MoSync and others comparison

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform

Are there any experienced developers to make a comparison between these two SDKs?
What have better learning curve for beginners? Is the deployment for many platforms easy the same in both? Any others sugestions about difference unvisible in the first contact working with these SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used MoSync, but I have made several games with Airplay SDK, for iPhone, Android, and bada. It's a very solid system with very good community support when you have questions. You need to know C (and a bit of C++ but mostly it's just C), but otherwise it's very easy to use. You can use a 3D API or a 2D API. They include lots of good examples. They have good profiling tools. It's great for people who like Visual Studio, with all the debugging advantages of that system. You can definitely make games for multiple platforms all from the comfort of your PC (or Mac, but I haven't tried the Mac version). I have a bit more about my experiences with it at [www.immortalcode.com](http://www.immortalcode.com).

Comment: Thanks M Katz for your answer. I like your blog:) Do you know any others interesting blogs where author write about his experience with Airplay?

Comment: The Airplay forum itself (https://www.airplaysdk.com/forum) contains a huge amount of information. By looking at the questions people are asking you can get a good sense of what people are doing with the SDK, what they are getting stuck on, etc. Note they also have a category where people announce the games they have made with Airplay SDK, so you get a good sense of what it can do.